# pip3.10 install virtualenv вызывает ошибку Fatal error in launcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-3.10

В системе есть несколько версий интерпретатора `python` и все они в `Path`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как в основном пользуюсь 3.7, то в директории `Python37` лежит файл `python.exe`, для того, чтобы командой `python main.py` вызывать именно 3.7 версию.

Проблема в том, что команда `pip3.10 install virtualenv` вызывает ошибку

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip3.10.exe" install virtualenv': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????
```

Это логично, ведь `python.exe` лежит только в `python37`. И данную ошибку можно исправить добавив `python.exe` в `Python310`. Но в такой ситуации в `Path` получается две директории в которых хранится `python.exe` и при выполнении команды `python` запустится интерпретатор `python310`.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при выполнении `python` в `cmd` запускался именно `python3.7`, а при `pip3.10 install virtualenv` устанавалась библиотека для `python 3.10`? Можно конечно всегда прописывать
`"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.exe" pip3.10.exe install virtualenv`
но по-моему застрелиться проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно удалять python.exe из дополнительных установок интерпретатора Python. Удалите дополнительные `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`, `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` из переменных окружения (Scripts по идее можно оставить), тогда через `python.exe` будет запускаться версия Python 3.7. Дополнительные версии интерпретатора запускайте через `py -3.9`или `py -3.10`.

Вместо `virtualenv` используйте стандартный модуль `venv`, его не нужно дополнительно устанавливать. venv запускайте нужной версией интерпретатора, например через `py -3.10 -m venv имя_окружения`

Comment: Работает, только откуда берется py.exe? его в переменных средах нет.

Comment: Он при установке Python (любой из новых версий, начиная с Python 3.3 вроде бы) ставится в `c:/windows`